# How would you translate the expression ''real world usage'' into French?

Tags: expressions

For some reason, “réel” or “dans le monde réel” doesn't sound right.

Comment: Can you provide a full English sentence using that expression?

Comment: Sure the original sentence is ''Understand how real world usage compares to track data''

Comment: Hmm, the sentence looks obscure to me in English. What means "track data" here, and is "real word usage" compared to it?

Comment: I would use "en conditions réelles" but share the same doubts as Jiliagre about the exact meaning of that sentence in English, whish is hard to deduct with no context. There are chances a litteral translations will sound odd so maybe you'll need a more idiomatic expression...

Answer (score 3):

I like @dimitris answer, but I would add two shorter options : « usage réel » and « utilisation réelle » which are both perfectly understandable in French.

My attempt at translating the full sentence :

> Comprendre dans quelle mesure l’[usage réel / utilisation réelle] est
>   comparable aux données de suivi.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/30224/13100) about ***usage réel*** or ***utilisation réelle***, especially in the example sentence provided. I think it is the best choice.

I just wanted to offer an alternative, which might not be appropriate in this specific example, but could work well elsewhere.

Common in Quebec, though I am unsure about other areas of the Francophony, is ***“dans la vraie vie”***. It is familiar, though not offensive enough to justify claiming it should be avoided in speech, even in a formal presentation :

> It’s all nice and good on paper, but in real world usage, people will almost always use *“on”* instead of *“nous”*.

...could become :

> C’est bien beau sur papier, mais **dans la vraie vie**, les gens utilisent pratiquement toujours *« on »* plutôt que *« nous »*