# Dans la vraie vie

Tags: expressions, usage

Très communément entendue au Québec pour contraster des situations théoriques ou idéales de celles qui surviennent dans la réalité, l’expression *« dans la vraie vie »* est par contre plus difficile à trouver à l’écrit, notamment dans les dictionnaires.

Sur [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/dans+la+vraie+vie.html), différents exemples sont présentés, et je remarque deux choses :

- L’expression ne s’utilise pas seulement dans ce contexte :
    → Connotation religieuse : *« ...évidence qu'il existe une connaissance littérale de la Parole de Dieu qui “tue”, au lieu de nous introduire dans la vraie vie. »*
    → Contraste avec la vie sur internet : *« ...malheureusement aussi sans permission et à des personnes inconnues dans la vraie vie. »*
    → Rappel que certaines situations ou certains états surviennent pour vrai, en ce sens un peu le contraire de ce que je présentais dans le premier paragraphe (c’est à dire qu’ici, la théorie, en dépit d’une certaine rareté du phénomène discuté, s’approche davantage de la réalité qu’on pourrait être porté à le croire) : *«  ...et à nous tenir au courant des défis que doivent relever les personnes faisant de l'épilepsie dans la vraie vie. »*
- Pratiquement tous les exemples contrastant une théorie considérée trop simpliste à la réalité de sa mise en pratique proviennent du Canada.

---

1. Cet usage est-il commun aussi ailleurs dans la Francophonie ?
2. Si non, serait-il néanmoins bien compris ?
3. Quel niveau de langue attribueriez-vous à l’expression ?

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi tu as un doute. Ça existe bel et bien ici aussi.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Simplement son absence dans les dictionnaires, mon manque d'expérience «dans ma vraie vie» de l'Europe, et les circonstances présentées dans la question sur les citations de Linguee...

Comment: Je ne vois pas pourquoi je ne saurais avoir un doute, puisque je ne suis pas «ici» et n'y ai jamais été...

Answer (score 3):

La semaine passée on m'a demandé ce que "je faisais dans la vraie vie", signifiant ailleurs que dans ma vie professionnelle.

Comme s'il y avait autre chose que le travail dans la vie...

Comment: J'adore votre réponse, mais aimerais un surplus d'infos, à savoir si vous venez d’Europe, d’Afrique, d’Amérique ou d’ailleurs. Merci de votre réponse inattendue!

Comment: @Montéedelait Utiliser "dans la vraie vie" pour parler en dehors de la vie profesionnelle est utilisé en tout cas en Europe (excepté Québec, je pense qu'il est utilisé partout).

Comment: J'ai grandi et habite en Suisse (Romande), mes parents habitent le Sud de la France, j'ai fait mes études à Lyon et mes grand-parents sont belges. Autant vous dire que pour moi, les accents et les régionalismes c'est la vraie vie pour de vrai.

Answer (score 1):

Le dictionnaire Livio comporte un lemme pour vraie vie. Wiki de même (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vraie_vie).

Or, la citation donnée par Livio est tirée par l'auteur Thomas Ouellet-St-Pierre.

https://premiereovation.com/artistes/fiche.aspx?IdArtiste=YXRtaUxxcTVmdlhqRmtzNXN1UUZsQT090

Je crois qu'il est Quebecois, n'est-ce pas ?

Récemment, vous avez donné une réponse formidable

[How would you translate the expression ''real world usage'' into French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30215/how-would-you-translate-the-expression-real-world-usage-into-french/30229#30229)

Je ne suis pas Français mais je n'ai pas eu quand même de difficultés de comprendre l'emploi de vraie vie dans le contexte.